Can I edit my existing WordPress template using Elementor?
I'm just a newbie. I have chosen this wordpress theme, and I've already added all the details that I want to include in my website using this theme. But with this existing pages already added, can I edit it using Elementor? If yes, how so?
I already installed the elementor plug in and I went to the Pages section but I can't see the "Edit with elementor" option.

well, it will not work or if it works it will show you as text widget and all of your elements will be displayed inside it. So technically it will work but won't be helpful. you will have to recreate everything to make it usable.
And as per my knowledge there are no page-builders that supports each other.
